# TIC TCP Conn Failed when running Swift project on my phone

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift. I built a simple application which works fine on the simulator. I am running the same on my device (iPhone 6s with iOS 11.0.2) and it's failing to connect to server.

getting these errors:

```
2017-10-26 18:16:02.489134-0400 myproj[1451:206438] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x1c0176800]: 1:61 Err(61)
2017-10-26 18:16:02.489771-0400 myproj[1451:206438] Task <0C30ADDC-4A0E-4815-A701-2EF0A7CF5F04>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2017-10-26 18:16:02.490293-0400 myproj[1451:206440] Task <0C30ADDC-4A0E-4815-A701-2EF0A7CF5F04>.<1> finished with error - code: -1004
```

Please help me understand this error.

EDIT:

Here is the code making that call to the server:

```
func postRequest(postData: NSDictionary, postHeaders: NSDictionary, endPoint: String,
                 onComplete: @escaping ((NSDictionary)->Void), callbackParams: NSDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()) {
    let url:URL = baseUrl.appendingPathComponent(endPoint)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
    var paramString = ""
    for (key, value) in postData{
        paramString = paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
    }

    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = postHeaders as? [String : String]
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
            return}
        let json: Any?
        do {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        }
        catch {
            return
        }
        var serverResponse = json as? NSDictionary
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            for (key, value) in serverResponse!{
                callbackParams.setValue(value, forKey: key as! String)
            }
            onComplete(callbackParams)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

EDIT:

[image: Adding screen shot of info.plist, I had set Allow Arbitrary Loads to True as indicated in other posts, but didn't solve]
Thanks!

Comment: you need to provide your code. and what is TIC?

Comment: @hasan83 "TIC TCP Conn Failed" is a standard error generated when there is a fundamental configuration issue (e.g. I've seen it in macOS apps where it hasn't been sandboxed and granted permission to initiate outbound network connections, etc.).

Comment: r u connecting to http or https? if its http you need to set your server url as safe to use in plist

Comment: I don't think it's App Transport Security Settings in the info.plist because that's often a different error code, but it's worth checking if you're doing http rather than https. Aster, I'd suggest you create a small reproducible example of the problem (spare us all of your parsing code and the like, but [give us just enough to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); i.e. create a blank project and see what you need to do to recreate the problem).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am adding code where I am making this http request, hopefully that helps. 
I have server running locally on my machine "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"

Comment: * It's a http call

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Error -1004 is `URLError.cannotConnectToHost`. It cannot connect to the server for some reason.

In comments, you say the URL is `http://127.0.0.1`. That is `localhost`, the current machine. If you use that URL on a physical phone, it's going to look for the web server *on the phone.* Lol. It works on the simulator, because the simulator *is* your computer, the `localhost`.

You need a URL that your iPhone can resolve to the machine running your web service. For example, find out what the IP for the computer running the web service on your local network, make sure your iPhone is on wifi on the same network, and then use that unique IP number for your computer on the LAN (likely something more like 192.168.0.x).

Comment: lol of course...was just blindly running on the phone as I was doing from the Xcode simulator without thinking thru..
Absolutely correct..Thanks a lot Rob!
All good now!

Comment: Happens to the best of us. I did the same thing for about 30 minutes and this answer saved me. +1

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem when i was sending/ receiving socket messages! I am using Socket.io and Firebase for push and the error was at the node.js backend. ***The error was that the mongoose version was deprecated***. Whenever this error arises at the iOS End, ask the node.js backend team to look for Red color crash logs. They will surely find the problem causing this error on frontend. Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

In my case i'm not changes the Local host IP address.

```
Example : @"http://Localhost/Host name/index.pnp/apiname?";
```

initially i'm used above URL, so i'm got the same error...

Later i changed in to Localhost to 190.177.0.22

```
Example : @"http://190.177.0.22/Host name/index.pnp/apiname?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another corner case if you using something like ngrok and it's still not working is the phone isn't connected to a service provider network or wifi.

In my case my main phone was working the second out of service phone was not.